# How to pass different confimap map values in helm chart kubernetes for different services?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

we have 9 microservices in our application. In this all the services have same yaml manifest file(deployment, service and configmap(to supply environment variable to containers)).

But when we try to get it as helm template. We couldn't able to pass different environment variable for different services.

We have been using same template by having different values.yaml file for different service. Is there any way to support different environment variables using same configmap.

Comment: Can you give a little more details on the problems you're having?  The two good ways to describe what you're doing are to have separate copies of the chart for each service with their local modifications, or to pass in settings via values files.  It sounds like you're attempting the second approach but having some trouble?

Answer (score 1):

a helm chart acts as a collection of templates, which you can (re-)use to deploy multiple services, especially in a microservices context.

you configure different deployments (and therefore different environments) with the same helm chart by providing values-files during installation, which contain the configuration that should be applied during installation.

values.yaml in the helm chart folder:

```
service:
  port: 123
```

microservice-a-values.yaml provided during installation:

```
service:
  port: 456
```

configmap template in the helm charts templates/ folder:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
data:
  port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
```

to run the installation and actually use the microservice-a-values.yaml, provide it when calling the helm install:

```
helm upgrade --install microservice-a --values microservice-a-values.yaml
```

remember that there is a "hierarchy" of provided values files: the last one wins and overwrites the previous ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @olge. But we have different environment variables for different services. Is there any way that we can pass all the environment variables as json file and changing the json files in values.yaml file for different services.

Comment: as described above, you can specify different values by providing different values-files. you have to ensure that the environments you wanna change can be set with a values file and then supply the values-file for the environment you wanna deploy to.